# Can I use an Optimus Card without switching?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I know about Bumblebee and stuff. But my notebook is like a desktop now, it is always powered by energy, without battery at all.

My goal is to use the NVIDIA card all the time, without the switching hiccups. It's possible on Ubuntu 12.10?

I have a GeForce 540M card with Intel 3000 as the Integrated Graphics Card. No luck with disabling Optimus on the BIOS.

Even if I want to use NVIDIA all the time, I still need Bumblebee?

I tried to install via apt the nvidia-current package but when I restart I got no Unity :(
Purged this driver and tried to install the direct downloaded from NVIDIA site, rebooting into recovery and installing without X Server and LightDM. No luck too.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to switch off Optimus if you don't have a command for that. I would suggest flashing the Bios and installing a mod but that's very expirienced stuff...

Installing `Nvidia-prime` and `prime-indicator`, rebooting and setting your driver to with you gc in max performance is probably the best thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Your system needs a switch on/off call in the BIOS. Check the bottom of this page to see if there is one:

https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux